# freemember logout error

Tags: freemember

Running EE v2.5.5 and FreeMember 2.1.1

I am using the following code to log out a user:

```
<a href="{exp:freemember:logout_url return="dashboard/register"}">logout</a>
```

clicking the link takes me to EE's system message page with the following message:

```
You are not authorized to perform the following action
```

am I implementing this wrong or is there a bug perhaps?

Here are links to my templates

logging out from here: http://pastie.org/6317009

any page I use for the return param creates the same error

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try upgrading to FreeMember 2.2? There was an unfinished version available on GitHub which some people managed to get a hold of which may be causing the error.

Comment: When I download FreeMember from git hub The latest version I get is 2.1.1 where could I get 2.2 ?

Comment: Is this only happening with the logout tag? Can you login and register using FreeMember without issue? Also, this may sound crazy, but are you definitely logged in?

Comment: definitely logged in, but glad you asked :) yes, it only happens on logout, login register are ok

Comment: am I missing something about the 2.2 release, didn't see it on github

Comment: No I think you already have 2.2, I just forgot to update config.php with the new version number. It's fixed now.

Comment: Thanks, I downloaded a new copy and ran module updates. The version number is correct at 2.2. I am still having the same loout issue though. Anything else I can do to help you troubleshoot?

Comment: I'm getting the same error with ee v2.7.3 and free member 2.3 (and Transcribe and Store) -- Does any one have any idea on what it could be? {if logged_in} <a href="{exp:freemember:logout_url return="/"}" class="btn btn-mini margin-t5"><i class="icon-off icon-white"></i> Log out&nbsp;</a> {/if} And I get sent to `http://thesite.com?ACT=83&return_url=%2F` with and an error msg of You are not authorized to perform this action This for a site member not a super admin. Any ideas greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error has been fixed in FreeMember 2.2.1, released today:

https://github.com/expressodev/freemember

Answer (score 1):

You are implementing the tag correctly [**according to the docs**](https://github.com/expressodev/freemember/wiki/Logout-Url-Tag).

This error is usually related to a member having incorrect access or issues with forms being processed in Secure Mode.

Things to try:

1. Change the return parameter to another URL, try return="/". If another URL works, something in that template is the problem so you'll need to reduce to find out what.
2. Disable the "[**Process Form Data in Secure Mode**](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/security_settings.html#process-form-data-in-secure-mode)" setting on the Security and Sessions page in the CP which is located here: Admin ‣ Security and Privacy ‣ Security and Sessions.

---

**EDIT**
With the new if of your template code, here are two things to try:

1. Change `{if logged_out}{redirect="/"}{/if}` to `{if logged_out}Logged out{/if}`. Does it show or same error?
2. Remove all code from the template except `{if logged_out}{redirect="/"}{/if}`
3. Change `{if logged_out}{redirect="/"}{/if}` to `{if logged_out}{redirect="/"}{if:else}ALL OTHER TEMPLATE CODE HERE{/if}` OR `{if logged_out}{redirect="/"}{/if} {if logged_in}ALL OTHER TEMPLATE CODE HERE{/if}`
4. Test a new template that just handles redirect with `{if logged_out}{redirect="/"}{/if} {if logged_in}{redirect="dashboard"}{/if}`
5. Test `{if logged_out}{redirect="{path=}"}{/if}` OR `{if logged_out}{redirect="http://www.domain.com"}{/if}`
6. Check the URL where you are seeing the message... is it the dashboard URL or the home page URL? It will tell you where the issue is.

Comment: After trying a different return param I'm still getting the same issue. Turning off secure mode sounds, well, insecure :)

Comment: Turning off secure mode and testing will just give you more information. Let me know the results after you test. You can turn the setting back on after you tests.

Comment: Okee dokee. After testing with secure mode set to no, I'm still experiencing the same behavior.

Comment: Can you post the template code for this page and the return page to www.pastie.org and add the links to your question. Perhaps something else in the pages is causing the issue.

Comment: Also, are you testing this with a SuperAdmin user or another group member login?

Comment: testing as a SuperAdmin

Comment: I added a template link in the original question, thanks

Comment: I added a number of troubleshooting options to try in my answer.

Comment: thanks for troubleshooting steps: removing {if loggedd_out}... had not effect. the url for the error is http://domain.local/?ACT=52&return_url=%2F so it is not a template at all by the looks of it

Comment: looks like it was an add-on bug, but very grateful for your in-depth troubleshooting